# Cross-domain AJAX request error on HTTP 200

Tags: php, ajax, facebook

I'm writing a very basic Facebook app, but I'm encountering an issue with cross-domain AJAX requests (using jQuery).

I've written a proxy page to make requests to the graph via cURL that I'm calling via AJAX. I can visit the page in the browser and see it has the correct output, but requesting the page via always causes jQuery to fire the error handler callback.

So I have two files:

Proxy, which does the cURL request

```
<?php
//Do some cURL requests, manipulate some data
//return it as JSON
print json_encode($data);
?>
```

The facebook canvas, which contains this AJAX call

```
$.getJSON("http://myDomain.com/proxy.php?get=stuff", 
          function(JSON)
          {
              alert("success");
          })
          .error(function(err)
          {
              alert("err");
          });
```

Inspecting the call with Firebug shows it returns with HTTP code `200 OK`, but the error handler is always fired, and no content is returned. *This happens whether I set `Content-Type: application/json` or not*.

I have written JSON-returning APIs in PHP before using AJAX and never had this trouble.

What could be causing the request to always trigger the error handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I experienced the same issue and my problem was the fact that there was a domain difference between the webpage and the API, due to the SSL.

The web page got a **HTTP** address (http://myDomain.com) and the content I was requesting with JQuery was on the **same domain but HTTPS** protocol (https://myDomain.com). The browser (Chrome in this case) considered that the domains were differents (the first one with **HTTP**, the second one with **HTTPS**), just because of the protocol, and because the request response type was "application/json", the browser did not allowed it.

**Basically, the request worked fine, but your browser did not allowed the response content.**

I had to add a "**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**" header to make it work. If you're in the same case, have a look there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control.

I hope that'll help you, I got a headache myself.